# Angular js is not printing the data of ng-init using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-init

I am a newbie and i am trying few angular js examples but when create 2 div elements and try to run the angular js program for it. the initialized array is getting printed for the second div and it is not getting printed for the first div when i am using ng-repeat. Can anyone tell me why it is happening.  I am not able to see any difference between the way 2 arrays have been initialized. The code is below.

```
<html data-ng-app>
<head>
<title>Angular js</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="name">{{name}}
<div class="container" data-ng-init="namess=['Hello','There','God','There']">
<h3>Looping with the ng-repeat Directive</h3>
    <h4>Data to loop through is initialized using ng-init</h4>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="Personname in namess">{{Personname}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="container" data-ng-init="names=['Dave','Napur','Heedy','Shriva']">
    <h3>Looping with the ng-repeat Directive</h3>
    <h4>Data to loop through is initialized using ng-init</h4>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
<footer>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
</footer>
</html>
```

The result i am getting is as below

```
Looping with the ng-repeat Directive

Data to loop through is initialized using ng-init

Looping with the ng-repeat Directive

Data to loop through is initialized using ng-init

Dave
Napur
Heedy
Shriva
```

Comment: It works. http://jsfiddle.net/cysa0cah/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in your console you will see an error about duplicates on the first `ng-repeat`. Because you have "There" in your array twice you need to add a `track by` to your `ng-repeat`. Try replacing it with this:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="Personname in namess track by $index">{{Personname}}</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are duplicate entries in your first array and if you check the console you can see the error "Error: [ngRepeat dupes]". Angular ngRepeat doesn't allow duplicate values. Check the following link for the details https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes .

To fix, either remove the duplicate entry (There) or use following:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="Personname in namess track by $index">{{Personname}}</li>
```

data-ng-repeat="Personname in namess track by $index, this should fix the problem.